# Error on symfony date form due to date format

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, date

I have the following code in order to have an input field and a little icon to open the datepicker. The problem is that the day can't be greater than 12, as if it was taking it as a month. I think I'm applying the format correctly (Symfony 2.8). But every time I set a date greater than 12 on the datepicker or manually and clicking out in another input, the input becomes red; the error says the format is not correct.

**Controller:**

```
 ->add('fecha_inicio',
            'date', array(
                'label'     => "Vigente desde",
                'input'     => 'datetime',
                'widget'    => 'single_text',
                'format'    => 'dd/MM/y',
                'max_length' => 10,
                'mapped'    => false,
                'required'  => false,
                'attr'      => array('type' => 'date',
                'data-type' => 'date',  'placeholder' => 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                'data'      => new \DateTime('now')
            ))
```

And I link it in a twig with JQuery like this:

**JQuery in html.twig:**

```
 $('#form_fecha_inicio').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        required: false,
        showOn:'button',
        buttonImageOnly:true,
        'buttonImage':'{{asset('img/icons20px/calendario.png')}}',
        buttonText:'Seleccionar Fecha',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. They only way after many tries and no way to find a solution. I finally found this one, which is **modifying the Jquery.validate.js** file inside the project.

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
    /*date: function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
    },*/
    date: function (value, element) {
  var miDate = value.split('/');
  var iMes = parseInt(miDate[1]) - 1;
  return this.optional(element) || 
         !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(miDate[2], iMes.toString(), miDate[0]));},
```